# Change input when div state changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this div and this input:

```
<fieldset>
    <input/>
    <label></label>
    <div class="toggle_box">
        <div class="switch"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I want the input to be `checked` when the state of `<div class="switch"></div>` changes:

```
<fieldset>
    <input checked="checked" />
    <label></label>
    <div class="toggle_box">
        <div class="switch" state="on"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Any idea how I would do that using jQuery?
Thank you :)

Comment: Where is the code that changes the state attribute to "on"?

Comment: Are you trying to add the attribute "state" to your div with a class of "switch"?

Comment: how are you changing the `state` attribute of the `div`?

Comment: State="on" gets added onClick by the user. The input is hidden using css so I need it to change.

Comment: You might be trying to simplify your code for the sake of brevity. Don't be afraid of putting in more code than might be necessary, we won't steal your ideas :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rjWc9i6f is the full file

Comment: We'll steal code... just not ideas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salut SnippetSpace!
I prepared here a **[JSFiddle D E M O](http://jsfiddle.net/QsxGz/1/)**

Hope this will help
ciao et bonne chance! :)

BTW,
I used:

```
$.fn.toggleChkBx = function() {
    if ($('.switch').attr('state') == 'on') { 
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).find(':input').attr('checked')); 
    }
}
```

And call it for Ex.:
$('.some_Element').click(function() {....

```
 $(this).parent().find(':input').toggleChkBx(); // RUN OUR fn
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code: [pastebin.com/rjWc9i6f](http://pastebin.com/rjWc9i6f)

Whenever you're setting the div state to on, also check the box. It's really that simple. It would be easier for you to manage with a function:

```
function SetState($switch, on)
{
    $switch.attr("state", on ? "on" : "off");
    $switch.closest("fieldset").find("input:checkbox").attr("checked", on);
}
```

and call this function like so:

```
SetState($(".switch"), true);
```

or from the context of your `.toggle_box` `div`

```
SetState($(this).find(".switch"), true);
```

or using your `target` variable:

```
SetState(target, true);
```